# Write a DataFrame to csv file with a custom row/line delimiter/separator

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I need to produce a delimited file where each row it separated by a '^' and columns are delimited by '|'.

There don't seem to be options to change the row delimiter for csv output type.

eg:

```py
df.coalesce(1).write\
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
.mode("overwrite")\
.option("header", "true")\
.option("sep","|")\
# no options for setting lineSep to '^' 
.save(destination_path)
```

Comment: Can you check this databricks url, wherein they have suggested to use, spark._jvm.java.lang.System.setProperty("line.separator", "\n") for custom line seperators?  https://forums.databricks.com/questions/12831/custom-line-separator.html

Comment: you can use option as **lineSep**, here default is \n . see https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/cb06209fc908bac6ce6a8f20653865489773cbc3/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameWriter.scala

Comment: @Prateek I can see the change, https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/23080, which specific spark version contains this change?

Comment: I cannot find that change in documentation for verion 2.4.4. https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.4/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameWriter

Comment: can you try using **option(key, value)** . Example option("lineSep","^")

Comment: Tried it on 2.4.4, it's not implemented yet.

Comment: It will be implemented in version 3.0. https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/23080#issuecomment-562220436

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution consists of to convert the DataFrame to rdd :

```
df.rdd.map(x=>x.mkString("^")).saveAsTextFile("OutCSV")
```

Answer (score 0):

In pyspark version 3+ there is an option to set line separator:

```
df.coalesce(1).write\
.format("com.databricks.spark.csv")\
.mode("overwrite")\
.option("header", "true")\
.option("sep","|")\
.option("lineSep","^")\
.save(destination_path)
```